# Extend Wordpress Theme Categories For Multiple Cities

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am working with categories in a directory WP theme. I am seeking how to expand the theme's core categories across multiple cities and types. The scenario is to create categories that are stored and selected at random to appear in the front-end Elementor carousel for each city page.

I have tried to create a parent (city) and child (category) but the problem is all terms appear in search functions and the sign-up submission form. I would also need to add a custom url for each category without having to manually update the urls on the backend post page each time the carousel updates?

The alternative it seems is to organise the images in folders for each city in media library and then adding the images to carousel with a link each time we update?